How to limit the period of the financial data pulled from yahoo finance using python
I have gotten the code to pull financial data from Yahoo Finance using Google Colab, but the code does not provide a way to limit the period of the data pulled.
This was the code that i used:
!pip install yahooquery

from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

stocks = ['^JKSE','ARMY.JK','ASPI.JK','ASRI.JK','ATAP.JK','BAPA.JK','BAPI.JK','BBSS.JK','BCIP.JK','BEST.JK','BIKA.JK','BIPP.JK','BKDP.JK','BKSL.JK','BSBK.JK','BSDE.JK','CBPE.JK','CITY.JK','COWL.JK','CPRI.JK','CSIS.JK','CTRA.JK','DADA.JK','DART.JK','DILD.JK','DMAS.JK','DUTI.JK','ELTY.JK','EMDE.JK','FMII.JK','FORZ.JK','GAMA.JK','GMTD.JK','GPRA.JK','GRIA.JK','HOMI.JK','INDO.JK','INPP.JK','JRPT.JK','KBAG.JK','KIJA.JK','KOCI.JK','LAND.JK','LCGP.JK','LPCK.JK','LPKR.JK','LPLI.JK','MDLN.JK','MKPI.JK','MMLP.JK','MPRO.JK','MTLA.JK','MTSM.JK','MYRX.JK','NASA.JK','NIRO.JK','NZIA.JK','OMRE.JK','PAMG.JK','PLIN.JK','POLI.JK','POLL.JK','POSA.JK','PPRO.JK','PUDP.JK','PURI.JK','PWON.JK','RBMS.JK','RDTX.JK','REAL.JK','RIMO.JK','RISE.JK','ROCK.JK','RODA.JK','SAGE.JK','SATU.JK','SMDM.JK','SMRA.JK','SWID.JK','TARA.JK','TRIN.JK','TRUE.JK','UANG.JK','URBN.JK','VAST.JK','WINR.JK'
]

print(stocks)
data = Ticker(stocks)

i_s = data.income_statement(frequency='a', trailing=False)
b_s = data.balance_sheet(frequency='a', trailing=False)
c_f = data.cash_flow(frequency='a', trailing=False)

i_s

b_s

c_f

i_s.to_csv('i_s.csv', index = True)

b_s.to_csv('b_s.csv', index = True)

c_f.to_csv('c_f.csv', index = True)

tickers = Ticker(['^JKSE','ARMY.JK','ASPI.JK','ASRI.JK','ATAP.JK','BAPA.JK','BAPI.JK','BBSS.JK','BCIP.JK','BEST.JK','BIKA.JK','BIPP.JK','BKDP.JK','BKSL.JK','BSBK.JK','BSDE.JK','CBPE.JK','CITY.JK','COWL.JK','CPRI.JK','CSIS.JK','CTRA.JK','DADA.JK','DART.JK','DILD.JK','DMAS.JK','DUTI.JK','ELTY.JK','EMDE.JK','FMII.JK','FORZ.JK','GAMA.JK','GMTD.JK','GPRA.JK','GRIA.JK','HOMI.JK','INDO.JK','INPP.JK','JRPT.JK','KBAG.JK','KIJA.JK','KOCI.JK','LAND.JK','LCGP.JK','LPCK.JK','LPKR.JK','LPLI.JK','MDLN.JK','MKPI.JK','MMLP.JK','MPRO.JK','MTLA.JK','MTSM.JK','MYRX.JK','NASA.JK','NIRO.JK','NZIA.JK','OMRE.JK','PAMG.JK','PLIN.JK','POLI.JK','POLL.JK','POSA.JK','PPRO.JK','PUDP.JK','PURI.JK','PWON.JK','RBMS.JK','RDTX.JK','REAL.JK','RIMO.JK','RISE.JK','ROCK.JK','RODA.JK','SAGE.JK','SATU.JK','SMDM.JK','SMRA.JK','SWID.JK','TARA.JK','TRIN.JK','TRUE.JK','UANG.JK','URBN.JK','VAST.JK','WINR.JK'
])

tickers.key_stats

Please help me find out how to pull the same financial data but with adjustable periods. Thank you.
